# How can I deploy a WAR file not as ROOT.war in AWS Elastic Beanstalk which was configured with Amazon AMI?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, tomcat, amazon-ec2

In my localhost my web app runs as localhost:8080/artifactId.
In production it just runs under www.example.com/ without the artifactId.

With this article and this , I understand, the war file should not be deployed as ROOT.war.

But I'm struck at how to deploy it under /wtpwebapps of tomcat.

Problems I am struck at 
1) Don't know where the tomcat directory in EC2 instance of BeanStalk?
2) Where is the script to modify in Ec2, so that further deployment, deploy properly under /wtpwebapps or some other way so that webapp works with artifact Id?
3) Do I need to have a customizable AMI to deploy a WAR file not as ROOT.war?
Please help. I'm struck at this for last 48 hours.

Comment: 1. SSH to your server, then use `whereis tomcat` or `which tomcat` to indentify location of Tomcat. 2. Take a look on [.ebextension](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html). 3. As root or note depend on your setting on aws file. Setting right `context path` of your web

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I tried both , but couldn't find out where tomcat is https://imgur.com/a/lMtkw

Comment: how about `/usr/share/tomcat7` or `/opt/tomcat7`, tomcatX depend on your version